# Identifying the current HEC for a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm writing a parallel Haskell program using Strategies. It's not doing what it's supposed to do, and I would like to inspect which Haskell Execution Context (HEC) a function is executed in.

Is there a getHEC call or something similar which I could use in my debug output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out which capability (i.e. CPU core) a Haskell thread is running on by calling `threadCapability` from `Control.Concurrent`.

If you're running your program with `+RTS -N`, there will be one OS-level thread (HEC) spawned per core, so the capability number returned by `threadCapability` will tell you which OS thread your `forkIO` green thread is running on. If, however, you are explicitly specifying the number of OS threads with `+RTS -Nn`, where `n` is some integer other than the number of cores on your system, this will probably be less useful to you.

You might also find [ThreadScope](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope) to be useful for debugging and visualizing the execution of parallel programs.

Comment: One other thing I should have mentioned: Keep in mind that the OS is free to reschedule threads onto different cores, so `threadCapability` called twice in the same Haskell thread has a small chance of returning different values, becoming more likely as more time elapses between calls. You can avoid this for debugging purposes if you lock a thread to a particular core by spawning the thread with `forkOn` instead of `forkIO`.